# Using StringFormat with XmlDataProvider

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml

I'm attempting to use a StringFormater with a XmlDataProvider with no success

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" XPath="/data" IsAsynchronous="False">
       <x:XData>
         <data xmlns="">
            <AMOUNT1>0.00</AMOUNT1>
         </data>
      </x:XData>
   </XmlDataProvider>
</Grid.Resources>


<TextBox x:Name="DollarAmount1" 
         Text = "{Binding XPath=/data/AMOUNT1, 
         StringFormat={0:C2}}"  
         DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}}" />
```

I have attempted all of the following StringFormats but none will reformat the data into a currency. Any suggestions?

```
StringFormat={0:C2}
StringFormat={}{0:C2}
StringFormat=\{0:C\}
```

Comment: `AMOUNT1` will come back as `String` which you then try to convert into `String`. Try with `IValueConverter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML values are strings.  You are trying to format a string into a  string :>

Add a converter class that implements **IValueConverter**.

**CODE**

```
 public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, 
                          Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      double outValue = 0;
      if (value != null)
      {
        outValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
      }
      return outValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
                              Type targetType, 
                              object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
      double outValue = 0;
      if (value != null)
      {
        outValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(outValue);
      }
      return outValue;
    }
```

}

Then add the converter to the binding.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="DollarAmount1"
             Text="{Binding 
                      Converter={StaticResource StringToDoubleConverter}, 
                      StringFormat=\{0:C\}, 
                      XPath=/data/AMOUNT1}"
                      DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData}}" />
```

Comment: Any way to just type the xml as a decimal to avoid a code behind?

Comment: XML is just a structured text file. How does it know that "3" an int, double, decimal, char or whatever. You'd need to put extra meta data in the file (AMOUNT dataType="int") or have some code "cast" the string to your desired type.   Having said that, You can include type information in an XML file, .NET includes some serialization classes that can read and write .NET classes to files.  But you still need code behind for that.