# Why isn't the comma seperator appearing in this textblock?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, string-formatting

This is one of those 'this should work!' things.
Here's the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=UnitStrength, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}"  Margin="0,0,15,0" FontFamily="BauderieScriptSSK Bold" FontSize="24"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

And here's the output:

[image]

Yes, this font has a comma (I also checked with the default Windows font and the comma doesn't appear, either).

Is there some kind of super-duper secret weirdness with WPF that I'm missing? I've also tried using other StringFormats to insert a comma but they throw a runtime error (in the XamlReader). This XAML is in a HiearchicalDataTemplate and I suspect that it is the comma that is giving the XMLReader kanniptions. Anybody else ever encounter this?

Any ideas?

Comment: Change "StringFormat={}{0:N0}" to StringFormat={0:N0}

Comment: That throws a runtime error, 'Character '0' was unexpected in string '0:N0'.  Invalid XAML type name.' Line number '38' and line position '62'. This XAML is in a HierarchicalDataTemplate and the XAMLReader doesn't like this (or other) StringFormats.

Comment: I've had this problem if the data type is not number. Is you UnitStrength a string data type by any chance?

Comment: Try the suggestions in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844066/string-format-integer-with-commas-no-decimal-places-and-nothing-for-0-values

Comment: Data is an integer.

Comment: I've checked out the other stackoverflow question and it doesn't work. I think the XamlReader barfs on the comma. Specifically, it throws a 'XamlParseException: 'Unexpected token 'None' in rule: 'MarkupExtension ::= '{' TYPENAME (Arguments)? @'}'', in '{Binding XPath=UnitStrength, StringFormat='{}{0:#,#.}''.' Line number '38' and line position '70'.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536122/using-stringformat-with-xmldataprovider

Comment: Tried that and it threw more runtime errors. I think that's the right idea, but there seems to be problems with the code.